# WPF: Resizing stackpanels with images at runtime

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, image-scaling, gridsplitter

I am attempting to create an application for a flight simulator
 aircraft where a user can preset the position and size of a window of
 a set of popup radio displays as seen in the first screenshot.

However, I have run into a bit of a problem. In the second
 screenshot, when I scale the main grid horizontally
 with a grid splitter, the images increase in size vertically as well
 as horizontally instead of remaining at their initial height. Any
 ideas how to solve this?
[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Comment: it's because the ViewBox will change it's  the control that it contains to fill the available area as much as possible

Comment: It still occurs even with the ViewBox removed. The images insist on scaling uniformly instead of only one axis.

Comment: Anyone else got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was to use a grid and set the Grid.Row the image was assigned to. Then by scaling the grid I could get the desired effect.

XAML:

```
        <Grid x:Name="spGrid" Height="154" Width="101" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="PosStart" MouseMove="PosDelta" MouseUp="PosEnd">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="spRow1" Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="spCol1" Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Width="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DragDelta="PanelXDelta" DragStarted="PanelXStart"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DragDelta="PanelYDelta" DragStarted="PanelYStart"/>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="spStack" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="imgKMA30" Source="UI/KMA30.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="imgKR165A" Source="UI/KX165A.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="2" x:Name="imgKX165" Source="UI/KX165.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="3" x:Name="imgKN62A" Source="UI/KN62A.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="4" x:Name="imgKR87" Source="UI/KR87.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="5" x:Name="imgKT74" Source="UI/KT74.jpg" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    private void PanelXDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        spGrid.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
    }

    private void PanelYDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        spGrid.Height += e.VerticalChange;
    }
```